# How to reduce elif statement use?

Tags: python

If I'm making a program that alloys you to translate words, is there a way to not use elif every tine and just write words to translate. This is what ive got now!

```
print("English to Exrian Dictionary")

search = input("Enter the word you would like to translate: ").lower()

if search == "ant":
    print("Ulf")
elif search == "back":
    print("Zuwp")
elif search == "ban":
    print("Zul")
elif search == "bat":
    print("Zuf")
elif search == "bye":
    print("Zio")
elif search == "wumohu":
    print("Camera")
elif search == "car":
    print("Wuh")
elif search == "carrot":
    print("Wuhhef")
elif search == "cat":
    print("Wuf")
elif search == "doctor":
    print("vewfeh")
elif search == "dog":
    print("Ves")
elif search == "duck":
    print("Vawp")
elif search == "egg":
    print("Oss")
elif search == "enter":
    print("Olfoh")
elif search == "experiment":
    print("Oxkohymolf")
elif search == "fat":
    print("Tuf")
elif search == "flower":
    print("Tnecoh")
elif search == "goal":
    print("Seun")
elif search == "goat":
    print("Seuf")
elif search == "hand":
    print("Rulv")
elif search == "hat":
    print("Ruf")
elif search == "hello":
    print("Ronne")
elif search == "hello":
    print("Ronne")
elif search == "house":
    print("Reago")
elif search == "hello":
    print("Ronne")
elif search == "information":
    print("Yltehmufyel")
elif search == "inspiration":
    print("Ylgkyhufyel")
elif search == "lawyer":
    print("Nucioh")
elif search == "no":
    print("Le")
elif search == "yes":
    print("Iog")
else:
    print("No results were found for '" + search + "'")
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Please instead type your code into the question.

Comment: A [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) seems appropriate.

Comment: Use a mapping. Check if `search` exists in the mapping and print its value, else *No results were found...*

Comment: First of all, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Secondly, you could use a switch case to cut the number of lines.

Comment: It's not an image, its a link. I'm on an iPad so it won't let's me do the control.

Comment: Is there's a way I can get a dictionary's with words in it.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj It's likely the OP is using Python 3. No version of Python has a "switch case".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `dict` object.

Example:

```
words = {'ant': 'Ulf', 'back': 'Zuwp', 'ban' : 'Zul'} # etc
try:
    print(words[search])
except KeyError as e:
    print("No results were found for '" + search + "'")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `dict` to map each input to the appropriate output.

```
print("English to Exrian Dictionary")
d = {"ant": "Ulf",
     "back": "Zuwp",
     # etc
    }

search = input("Enter the word you would like to translate: ").lower()

if search in d:
    print(d[search])
else:
    print("No results were found for '" + search + "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
def translate(item):
try:
    return {
        'ant': "Ulf",
        'back': "Zuwp",
        'ban': "Zul"
    }[item]
except KeyError as e:
    return "No results were found for '" + search + "'"

print("English to Exrian Dictionary")

search = raw_input("Enter the word you would like to translate: ").lower()

print translate(search)
```